# How to make sure that the config has only one line

Tags: ansible

My playbook has the following task to set a static IPv6 address:

```yaml
- name: Configure stable IPv6
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/dhcpcd.conf
    regexp: '^static ipv6_address='
    line: "static ip6_address=2001::2222/64"
    state: present
  notify: Restart dhcpcd
```

My server has the following content in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file:

```
# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
static ip6_address=2001::0000/64
static ip6_address=2001::1111/64
```

When I run the playbook, ansible adds an additional line instead of replacing the existing two lines:

```
# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
static ip6_address=2001::0000/64
static ip6_address=2001::1111/64
static ip6_address=2001::2222/64
```

How can I get ansible to just set one IP address? I would like my config to look like:

```
# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
static ip6_address=2001::2222/64
```

The solution should:

- add a line if there are no lines present in the config
- remove all the matching lines if present and replace them with a new single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to make sure that the config has only one line? ... The solution should add a line if there are no lines present in the config,
> remove all ... lines ... and replace them with a new single line*

According your current description there seems to be absolute no need for any complex CHECK or IF THEN ELSE ELSEIF or similar approach. Just use the [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) or [`copy` with Parameter `content`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-content) to provide the desired state in a configuration file.

If that single line `static ip6_address=2001::2222/64` should be the final state, just declare it. A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - copy:
      content: 'static ip6_address=2001::2222/64'
      dest: dhcpcd.conf
```

will result into the requested output.

Answer (score 1):

Given the file for testing

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf 
# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
static ip6_address=2001::0000/64
static ip6_address=2001::1111/64
```

Put the configuration data into a list

```yaml
    dhcpcd_conf:
      - {key: static ip6_address, value: 2001::2222/64}
```

Remove the duplicate parameters but the first one

```yaml
    - name: "Remove duplicate parameters from dhcpcd.conf"
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
        after: '{{ item.key }}(\s|=)'
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}(\s|=).*$'
      loop: "{{ dhcpcd_conf }}"
```

gives (running with options --check --diff)

```yaml
--- before: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
+++ after: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
@@ -2,4 +2,4 @@
 #interface eth0
 #fallback static_eth0
 static ip6_address=2001::0000/64
-static ip6_address=2001::1111/64
```

If you want to keep the last match replace *after* with *before*

```yaml
    - name: "Remove duplicate parameters from dhcpcd.conf"
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
        before: '{{ item.key }}(\s|=)'
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}(\s|=).*$'
      loop: "{{ dhcpcd_conf }}"
```

Configure the file

```yaml
    - name: "Configure dhcpcd.conf"
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}(\s|=).*$'
        line: "{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ dhcpcd_conf }}"
```

gives (running with options --check --diff)

```yaml
--- before: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf (content)
+++ after: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf (content)
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 # fallback to static profile on eth0
 #interface eth0
 #fallback static_eth0
-static ip6_address=2001::0000/64
+static ip6_address=2001::2222/64
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dhcpcd_conf:
      - {key: static ip6_address, value: 2001::2222/64}

  tasks:

    - name: "Remove duplicate parameters from dhcpcd.conf"
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
        after: '{{ item.key }}(\s|=)'
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}(\s|=).*$'
      loop: "{{ dhcpcd_conf }}"
      tags: duplicates

    - name: "Configure dhcpcd.conf"
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}(\s|=).*$'
        line: "{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ dhcpcd_conf }}"
      tags: configure
```

The result

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/test/dhcpcd.conf 
# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
static ip6_address=2001::2222/64
```